Was Adam given the benefit of the doubt?
We read in Gen 3:8-11( KJV) how Adam and Eve face trial for disobedience

And they heard the voice of the Lord God walking in the garden in the cool of the day: and Adam and his wife hid themselves from the presence of the Lord God amongst the trees of the garden. And the Lord God called unto Adam, and said unto him, Where art thou? And he said, I heard thy voice in the garden, and I was afraid, because I was naked; and I hid myself.And he said, Who told thee that thou wast naked ? Hast thou eaten of the tree, whereof I commanded thee that thou shouldest not eat?

Earlier God had told Adam not to eat the fruit lest he should die the same day ( Gen 2:17). But the punishment actually  given is that Adam should toil on the ground till he would return to it ( Gen 3:19). And Gen 5:5 says that Adam lived upto age 930. In effect, he had a delayed and lenient punishment.
Why was Adam given a lenient punishment ?  Was he  given the 'benefit of the doubt' in that he had been deceived by the Devil ?

Here, "lest he should die the same day" assumes that "for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die means his death would be that literal day. But it's not clear that it definitely doesn't mean that on that day he would continue to live, but now subject to death, certain to eventually die. ¶

Which 'doubt' were you thinking of, please?
Purely that he had been deceived by the Devil, or what?
Have I been wrong in my life-long supposition that while indeed, Eve was seduced by Satan, Adam merely followed Eve? Will you be more clear?

Robbie Goodwin, Adam was not merely following Eve. Both of them had been told of the forbidden fruit. It was up to him to correct her, if she thought it right to eat it .

' Benefit of the doubt' is a term used in legal parlance. If refers to the clemency shown to the charged person , taking  into consideration among others, the circumstances leading to the alleged misdeed.

Looking at the more literal translations, it is "dying you shall die" in Genesis 2:17
Dying you shall die

The Hebrew phrase translated into English as “surely die” sounds really strange to non-Hebrew ears. The literal translation is, “dying you shall die.” According to Hebrew grammars this phrase is a Hebrew idiom meant to express certainty by repeating the word. 
https://ready4eternity.com/dying-you-shall-die/

Literal Standard Version

but from the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil, you do not eat from it, for in the day of your eating from it—dying you die.”

Young's Literal Translation

and of the tree of knowledge of good and evil, thou dost not eat of it, for in the day of thine eating of it -- dying thou dost die.'

Smith's Literal Translation

But from the tree to know good and evil thou shalt not eat from it, for in the day of thy eating from it, dying, thou shalt die.

After Adam disobeyed God and ate  of the forbidden tree, God said to him :

"in the sweat of your face, you shall eat bread, till you return into the ground; for out of it you were taken: for dust you are, and unto dust, shall you return.
Genesis 3:17-19

Death is a return to the ground;
Job 10:9, Job 1: 20-22
Job 30:22,23; 34:12-15

All go to one place; all were from dust, and all turned back to dust.
Ecclesiastes3:20

OP's question,

In effect, he had a delayed and lenient punishment.
Why was Adam given a lenient punishment ? Was he given the 'benefit of the doubt' in that he had been deceived by the Devil ?

God's word took effect immediately as dying set in as we can see by the fear by watching Adam  and Eve hide from God.  God did not hide from them.  Dying was a long process.
The greatest lie by the devil that still deceives many is that they  will not die, that they are immortal and still live on after death.
It was only Jesus who brought immortality and light

but it has now been revealed through the appearing of our Savior Christ Jesus, who abolished death and brought life and immortality to light through the gospel. 2 Tim.1:10


Cognate: 861 aphtharsía – properly, no-corruption (unable to experience deterioration); incorruptibility (not perishable), i.e. lacking the very capacity to decay or constitutionally break down.  See 862a (aphthartos).

Jesus appearing illuminates life.

Usage: The verb "phótizó" primarily means to give light or to illuminate. In the New Testament, it is often used metaphorically to describe the act of enlightening the mind or spirit, bringing understanding or revelation. It conveys the idea of making something clear or manifest, often in a spiritual or moral sense.

God did keep His word and like Adam died so death was passed to all men.
Satan's lie was you shall   not die, many believe that after they die they continue to live on somewhere else. That is a deception that has deceived many.
Life, resurrection being made in corruptible only comes through Christ's life.

Very interesting insight... dying you must die would mean that they would begin dying on the day of eating and this process of dying would ultimately result in death completed.  Thanks for highlighting this.

I would challenge the OP's assumption that Adam's punishment was lenient. There are various interpretations as to what the text means when it says "in the day you eat of it you shall die," and several of them understand Adam's punishment to be carried out as just God warned it would be.

Condemned to die, began to die.  Ramban (Nachmanides) understands this to mean that on that very day, Adam was condemned to die. Several Christian commentators more or less agree: Adam began to die on that day.

That day was not literal. Since a day to the Lord is 1,000 years to us (Psalm 90:4), Adam did actually die on "that day," but not during that 24-hour period. Since he would have lived forever otherwise, his lifetime was just a day in God's eyes.

Death not literal. The death of Adam was not literal. He died spiritually on that day, but his body lived on.


Conclusion: Adam's punishment was not necessarily lenient. There are several ways to understand that God never actually meant that Adam would literally die on the very day that he ate of the fruit.

Thanks, Dan Fefferman. I hope you don't take Palm 90:4 in literal sense. 1000 years would only mean a very very big period of time.

"Condemned to die": compare with Ezekiel 18:4's "the soul that sinneth, it shall die", where the death is sure, but not immediate, or 2 Samuel 6:7 where death was immediate after touching the Ark. For Adam, death was not immediate; it immediately became inevitable.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan... I do not take Psalm 90:4 literally, but some people do use it to explain that Adam did in fact die on the "day" that he sinned.

The pertinent text, not quoted but alluded to by the OP is Gen 2:17, correctly translated by most versions (eg, NASB)

but from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat,
for on the day that you eat from it you will certainly die.

Let us observe several things about this pivotal verse.
1. Last two words
The last two words of this verse in the Hebrew are simply the same verb (in two different forms) מֹ֥ות תָּמֽוּת = literally "die dying". However, as any Hebrew grammar will show, this is simply the Hebrew way of expressing what most modern translation correctly say, "surely die"; that the repeated verb simply expresses the certainty/surety of what is being said.
2. The Change
Before Adam and Eve sinned, let us review what they had:

eternal life - they would never die
they never aged physically
food was abundant and easy to obtain
daily personal access and communion with God

After Adam and Eve sinned, we are told the following from Gen 3:17-19

the ground is cursed and would require much more effort to find and grow food
thorns and thistles would be menace in farming
man would age physically
man would finally die of old age and other causes.  This is evidenced by their loss of access to the tree of life which prevent them living forever.
man lost face-to-face communion with God (Adam and Eve hid themselves)
man died spiritually and needed a Savior according to V15.  This is also evidenced by the garments required to both cover their physical nakedness and the death of the animals to provide the skins which resulted in regular animal sacrifices that pointed to the coming Messiah.

Note that all this either occurred or began to occur on the very day they sinned.  This was very great punishment indeed - the only leniency offered by God was the infinite offer of grace in a Savior in the future Messiah!

Claiming that God has doubt is against His omniscience. God certainly does not give anyone the "benefit of doubt".
To understand the meaning of death in Genesis 2:17, we must also consider the significance of the tree of life, as described in Genesis 3:22

And the Lord God said, “The man has now become like one of us, knowing good and evil. He must not be allowed to reach out his hand and take also from the tree of life and eat, and live forever. (NIV)

Therefore, when Adam and Eve could continue to eat from the tree of life, they would have lived forever in Eden. However, after being expelled from Eden, they were destined to die - not because they ate the fruit given by the serpent, but because they could no longer eat from the tree of life.
Did the Lord give Adam a lenient punishment by allowing him to live to 930 years old? What can we say now that the average human lifespan is only around 80 years?
Death in Genesis 2:17 symbolizes the price of sin, as Paul notes in Romans 6:23:

For the wages of sin is death, but the gift of God is eternal life in Christ Jesus our Lord. (NIV)

Since everyone has sinned (Romans 3:23), everyone will die regardless of how long they live on earth. However, those who remain faithful in Christ will receive the gift of God: eternal life.
